# Run a perl script in a browser via a link

Tags: apache-2.4, web-server, perl, web-applications, cgi

I'm attempting to get a perl script up and running on Oracle Linux 8.5.

My Apache server and virtual hosts work with static html.

My test virtual host, fnu, has a very basic perl script named hw.pl in /var/www/fnu:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
print "Hello, World. This is fnu.";
```

I have a link from `index.html` to `hw.pl`, permissions open and owner set to `apache`:

```
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 apache apache 89 Jun  4 20:59 hw.pl
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 apache apache  5 Jun  4 20:59 index.html -> hw.pl
```

Here's the site config in `/etc/httpd/conf.d`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
DocumentRoot "/var/www/fnu/"
ServerName fnu.[obscured].net
ServerAlias fnu
ErrorLog /var/log/fnu/error.log
CustomLog /var/log/fnu/request.log combined
<\/VirtualHost>

<Directory "/var/www/fnu">
    Options +ExecCGI +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl
<\/Directory>
```

If I point a browser to `fnu/hw.pl`, I get the result I expect - the script output. If I point the browser to `fnu/`, I get the contents of the file. So, it's following the link, but it's not running it as a perl script once it gets there. Nothing useful in `/var/log/fnu/error.log`.

SELinux is set to Permissive.

I appreciate any assistance.

[Script output as expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lA8Hy.png)

[Script file contents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wse20.png)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? is your goal to have the Perl script run when you browse to the directory `fnu/`?

Answer (score 0):

it's reading index.html as an html file.

one way to rectify this is to tell apache to execute .phtml files as perl.

to do this you locate the:

```
<IfModule dir_module>
     DirectoryIndex index.html index.phtml index.php
</IfModule>
```

in your httpd configurations and add index.phtml to the `DirectoryIndex` list as shown above.

then you want to `AddHandler cgi-script .phtml` and rename your link to index.phtml.

this *should* work, but it's been many years since i have used cgi in apache.

another way to do this is to use **SSI** *(Server Side Includes)* with **mod_include**. with this you can create an index.html and `<!--#include virtual="/path/to/hw.pl" -->` OR `<!--#exec cmd="hw.pl" -->`

i can't remember which is better, but depending on what your script does you can read the documentation and figure out the best method.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, I got on the trail of another resource and was able to solve this using `SetHandler` in the config instead of `AddHandler`. I realize this may be an over-broad solution in some cases but it is doing what I want here.

```
<Directory "/var/www/fnu">
    SetHandler cgi-script
    Options +ExecCGI +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
<\/Directory>
```

The script now runs when I browse to `fnu/`.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution.  Note that this will mean you cannot serve any static files from this directory.  Everything in there will be treated as a CGI script.  You could make `index.pl` to `DirectoryIndex`, symlink that to your script and base your handlers on extensions you will be able to host both in there.